# how to reload current page after api call in ionic 4

Tags: android, angular, ionic4, refresh, reload

I want to reload the page after calling API in ionic 4.

In login, I store user value in localStorage: `localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userDeatil));`

After login, it navigates to the tabs pages, In tab1 I check if the user is approved by an admin or not and according to that value message is shown on the screen.

In tab1 I am using **ion-refresher** to refresh the page and call API to check whether the user is approved or not.

After refreshing page API is called if the user is approved then the status is changed in local storage but my UI is not changed. After closing an APP the UI is changed or if I am checking it in localhost then after refreshing that page.

How to update UI instant after calling an API.

This problem is solved by adding :

**`window.location.reload();`**

But a new issue is that after reloading page white screen appears for a while.

**How to remove that white screen?**

**.html**

```
<ion-refresher #refresherRef slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="load($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content
    pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"
    pullingText="Pull to refresh"
    refreshingSpinner="circles"
    refreshingText="Refreshing...">
    </ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>

  <div *ngIf="userData.userStatus == 2" class="emplty_class">
    Your request has been pending.
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="userData.userStatus == 1">
    Your request is approved.
  </div>
```

**.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('this.router.url', this.router.url);
    // alert(this.router.url);
    this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
      if (this.router.url == '/tabs/tab1') {
        this.closingApp();
      }
    });
  }

ionViewWillEnter() {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
    this.usderDetails = data;
    for (let data of this.usderDetails) {
      this.userData.userId = data.id;
      this.userData.userStatus = data.status;
      console.log(this.userData.userStatus);
    }
  }

load(refresher) {
    if(this.userData.userStatus == "2"){
      let postData = new FormData();
      postData.append('user_id', this.userData.userId);

      this.authService.postData(postData, "is_verified_or_not.php").then((result) => {
        this.responseData = result;

        this.success = this.responseData.success;
        if (this.success == 1) {
          refresher.target.complete();
          // refresher.complete();
          let userDeatil = this.responseData.users_details;
          localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userDeatil));
          for (let data1 of userDeatil) {
            let userStatus = data1.status;
            localStorage.setItem('userStatus', JSON.stringify(userStatus));
            console.log("userStatus" + userStatus);
          }
        } else {
          this.message = this.responseData.message;  
          refresher.target.complete();
          this.showToast(this.message);
        }
      }, (err) => {
        refresher.target.complete();
        console.log("Error", err);
      });
    } else{
      refresher.target.complete();
      console.log("User is already approved: " + this.userData.userStatus);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `window.location.reload()`?

Comment: Can you please tell me where to put this. I am new to ionic. I am learning it. Thanks.!

Comment: Once the API call is successful, you can use that code snippet i.e here `if (this.success == 1) {` at the end of that block.

Comment: I have another doubt If u can help me. In profile page user info is shown and after clicking on edit profile when API is called on the success of API I use `this.navCtrl.pop();` and `this.router.navigate(['/tabs/tab2']);` I tried both and in profile page `ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.getData();
  }` called user Profile info in ionViewWillEnter() but updated value is not shown. @NicholasK

Comment: After the reloading page, a white screen appears. How to remove a white screen? @NicholasK

Comment: Check your console, something is probably failing...

Comment: not in localhost in real device